# Adding buttons to an android app to initiate ssh'ing into a remote machine

Tags: java, android

I have a working ssh app interface but I was wondering how would I implement two buttons -one to connect via ssh and a button to disconnect from the ssh. This is using the android studio. Any implementation I have tried has led to 'unresolved' variables within the code.
I currently have implemented two buttons in the layout file-one with an on click message 'go' and on with an on click message 'stop'. I thought it might be easier than an onclicklistener but any solution is welcome.
This is the activity code

```
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;

import com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelExec;
import com.jcraft.jsch.JSch;
import com.jcraft.jsch.Session;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.util.Properties;


public class mainmenu extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_mainmenu);

        new AsyncTask<Integer, Void, Void>() {
            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(Integer... params) {
                try {
                    executeRemoteCommand("username", "password", "IP", 22);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return null;
            }
        }.execute(1);
    }

        public static String executeRemoteCommand (String username, String password, String hostname,
        int port)
            throws Exception {


            JSch jsch = new JSch();
            Session session = jsch.getSession(username, hostname, port);
            session.setPassword(password);

            // Avoid asking for key confirmation
            Properties prop = new Properties();
            prop.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
            session.setConfig(prop);

            session.connect();

            // SSH Channel

            // Execute comman

            ChannelExec channelssh = (ChannelExec)
                    session.openChannel("exec");
            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            channelssh.setOutputStream(baos);
            channelssh.setCommand(" 1");
            channelssh.connect();


            channelssh.disconnect();

            return baos.toString();

    }
}
```

Every time I try to make 'session' a static variable it throws up an error and says it is unresolved when I try this button construct:

```
public void go (void){
channelssh.connect()
}
```